# English equivalent of the Argentinian idiom "not a single puppet was left with its head on"

Tags: idiom-requests, spanish

I'm looking for an English idiom related to this one, pretty odd, heard in Argentina:

"Not a single puppet is left with its head on.", or maybe "To chop off every puppet's head." (No dejar títere con cabeza).

The main use of this idiom is sexual related; it refers to somebody (man or woman) who is known for having had sex with most of the people in his/her circle of relationships.

"Have you met Cindy already? Be careful; ***she doesn't leave a single puppet with its head on**"*.

Nevertheless, this idiom can be used in other contexts, for example:

"As soon as the low productivity reports arrived, the company took immediate measures. ***Not a single puppet was left with its head on:*** two employees were relocated, while the remaining three were fired."

Maybe there's an idiom related to the first example and another different to the second one.

Comment: There's no "puppet-related" idiom like this in English. But we do have the idiomatic usage [***heads will roll.***](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/heads-will-roll) *If you say that heads will roll as a result of something bad that has happened, you mean that people will be punished for it, especially by losing their jobs.* Presumably the metaphoric reference is to heads rolling into the basket by the guillotine, in the French Revolution.

Comment: …or off the chopping block at the Tower of London (just ask Anne Boleyn)

Comment: I can think of two expressions, bicycle and dog related, but as I can't balance them with male-targeted ones I won't give them.

Comment: Somewhat related: [Is "anything in a skirt" a popular idiom? Does it have special overttones?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/114598/is-anything-in-a-skirt-a-popular-idiom-does-it-have-special-overtones)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For the promiscuity sense, there is the informal expression *put it about*, used especially in the UK:

> **put it about** [idiom] [UK] [informal] (also *put yourself about*)
>
> to have sex with a lot of different people

[[Cambridge Dictionary](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/put-it-about)]

..................

For the 'none left standing' sense, one could use *clear-out*:

**clear out** ...

> 5. (tr) to get rid of (employees, players, etc, that are no longer required)

[Cambridge Dictionary](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/clear-out)

> - The following season saw another eighth place finish and following a shareholder revolt, there was a boardroom clear-out.

[[Cambridge Dictionary](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/clear-out); from Wikipedia]

And **none left standing** is often used informally to show a total wipeout (violent or metaphorically with regard to say employees); it even has the initialism NLS.

(430 000 raw Google hits for "total wipeout" shows the tautology is idiomatic.)

Answer (score 1):

Maybe not precisely in their immediate circle of relationships always, but **[been around the block](https://grammarist.com/idiom/been-around-the-block/)** has a close meaning to the first case, and could be replaced with it, depending on the context

> In some circumstances, the phrase means the person in question is sexually experienced. This meaning is particularly common in British English.

And as comments have pointed out, **[heads will roll](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/heads%20will%20roll)** fits the second case,

> used to say that people will be severely punished or will lose their jobs because of something that has happened

Though this isn't used in past tense usually. That may be more like a **[blood bath](https://www.dictionary.com/browse/bloodbath)**

> Informal. a period of disastrous loss or reversal